# Java Inheritance With Orders and CreditOrders Issue

Tags: java, inheritance

SMC accepts orders and credit orders from their clients. For an order, the client pays the order value in advance. For credit orders, the SMC credits the clients with the full dollar value of the order (in other words, the client should not pay in advance for the ordered products). For credit orders, the client and the SMC representatives negotiate the interest (as percentage of the order value) that will be paid by the client on top of the order dollar value, when the ordered items are delivered. The interest value range should be between 10 and 20.

For the First section I believe I have done correctly. (The class Order defines the instance variables orderId, clientName and orderValue. It also defines a constructor with arguments, the method toString and and get/set type methods for the instance variables.)

```
public class Order {

public int orderId;
public String clientName;
public int orderValue;

/**
 * @param orderId
 * @param clientName
 * @param orderValue
 */
public Order(int orderId, String clientName, int orderValue) {
    super();
    this.orderId = orderId;
    this.clientName = clientName;
    this.orderValue = orderValue;
}

/**
 * @return the orderId
 */
public int getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
}

/**
 * @param orderId the orderId to set
 */
public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}

/**
 * @return the clientName
 */
public String getClientName() {
    return clientName;
}

/**
 * @param clientName the clientName to set
 */
public void setClientName(String clientName) {
    this.clientName = clientName;
}

/**
 * @return the orderValue
 */
public int getOrderValue() {
    return orderValue;
}

/**
 * @param orderValue the orderValue to set
 */
public void setOrderValue(int orderValue) {
    this.orderValue = orderValue;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Order [orderId=" + orderId + ", clientName=" + clientName
            + ", orderValue=" + orderValue + "]";
}


}
```

Then for the Second section I am confused and this is what I have so far.(The class CreditOrder inherits the class Order. This class inherits the instance variables of class Order and defines its specific instance variable interest. It also defines a constructor with arguments, the get/set methods for the instance variable interest, the new method getCreditOrderTotalValue and overrides the method toString.) I am not sure if the interest is correctly done and I am not sure on what do with "getCreditOrderTotalValue" and to override a toString method.

```
public class CreditOrder extends Order {

public int interest;

public CreditOrder(int orderId, String clientName, int orderValue) {
    super(orderId, clientName, orderValue);

}

/**
 * @return the interest
 */
public int getInterest() {
    return interest;
}

/**
 * @param interest
 *            the interest to set
 */
public void setInterest(int interest) {
    this.interest = interest;
}

    //getCreditOrderTotalValue

    //toString
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to be clear about the inheritance and how things work in object oriented paradigm. The toString() method is coming from the java.lang.Object and inherited automatically to all objects by default. And the proper use of access specifiers in case of achieving inheritance (protected).

So if I am allowed to suggest some changes in the class structure, it will be...

```
public class Order {
   private int orderValue;
   //getters and setters, make protected
   public Order(int orderValue) {
      this.orderValue = orderValue;
   }
   protected int calculateOrderValue() {
      return this.orderValue;
   }
}
public class CreditOrder extends Order {
   private int orderValue;
   private float interestRate;
   //getters and setters for interestRate
   public CreditOrder(int orderValue, float interestRate) {
     super(orderValue);
     this.orderValue = orderValue;
     this.interestRate = interestRate;
   }
   public int calculateOrderValue() {
      return getOrderValue() * getInterestRate();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am not seeing your modifications and my comments any more. What happened?

Comment: I just got rid of it since it seemed wrong. I am still trying to figure for the Credit Order were SMC credits the clients with the full dollar value of the order (in other words, the client should not pay in advance for the ordered products). For credit orders, the client and the SMC representatives negotiate the interest (as percentage of the order value) that will be paid by the client on top of the order dollar value, when the ordered items are delivered. The interest value range should be between 10 and 20.